# Can test cases have "shared steps" in HP Quality Center?

Tags: testcase, hp-quality-center

[Microsoft Test Manager](http://www.edsquared.com/2012/03/28/Difference+Between+Microsoft+Test+Manager+And+Visual+Studio+Test+Professional.aspx) has the concept of [shared steps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286655.aspx).

**Example**

Say you have 3 test cases which all start with

1. Start application
2. Enter user name "admin"
3. Enter password "default!password"
4. Click button "Log in"

then you can create a so called "[shared step](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286655.aspx)" called "Log in to application" and insert it into each of the three test cases.

If the shared step "Log in to application" needs to updated, it can be done in one place and all 3 test cases will be updated.

**Question**

Does HP Quality Center have such a feature?

If so, could you please point me to a tutorial or to the documentation, preferably with screenshots?

**Research**

I haven't worked with HP Quality Center yet. I've done a few Google searches but wasn't successful in answering the question myself.

Google searches

- [HP Quality Center shared steps](https://www.google.ch/search?q=HP%20Quality%20Center%20shared%20steps)
- [HP Quality Center common steps](https://www.google.ch/search?q=HP%20Quality%20Center%20common%20steps)
- [HP Quality Center template for test steps](https://www.google.ch/search?q=HP%20Quality%20Center%20template%20for%20test%20steps)
- [HP Quality Center share common test steps across multiple test cases](https://www.google.ch/search?q=HP%20Quality%20Center%20share%20common%20test%20steps%20across%20multiple%20test%20cases)

Comment: Try a search for "HP Quality Center test case requirements linking". You can basically set up a test case with requirements and those requirements can be other test cases, such as "logging in as admin". I don't recall the exact steps to do this, so just adding a comment rather than a full on answer :=)  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use test case templates. These test case templates will be available when you a creating steps for test cases.

Comment: Rey, could you expand on this with a little bit of a walk through? It will help future visitors and will also increase the search footprint to get the right information to the people that need it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Bit late but:

just create a new test plans - add test steps and save/check-in.
Then in the tree-view right click the created testplan and click on 'Mark as Template Test'.

Now when you create a new testplan or modify an existing one, you can right-click on a test step and select 'Call to test'. Then select the template test u created before.

This helps to share test steps with multiple tests easily and maintain them at one place.