# How to reuse test steps in HP ALM test plan?

Tags: test-design, quality-center, test-planning, hp-quality-center, hp-alm

I'd like to reuse the same sequence of steps in different test scenarious.

For example, scenario of testing printing functionality and testing calculation functionality both need address entering. So it would be better to reuse these steps (enter City, Street, Building, Appartment Number).

Can I create Address filling pattern? And how can I add it to another test instance between it's test steps?

**EDIT**

As it was mentioned by @bish we can copy test steps:

[image: Copy steps to clipboard]

But it's a copy by value, not by link. So when you add country to the address pattern it will not be in test instances where you copied the steps (in the print testing, in the calculation testing).

Comment: You can copy & paste the steps from test A to test B

Comment: @bish, copying is not actualy what I need: you copy steps from test A to B, C, D..., then you change basic pattern in A, but it does not change anything in B, C, D... So it's not fully reusable test scenario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. For this you need to save your common/shared test steps in a new test case and then change it to a template using **'Mark as Template Test'**. Then where ever you need these shared steps, open that test case and in the test step section of that case select the option **'Call to Test'** and then select the shared test case template which you want to import.

[image: Call to Test Button]

This way when you change the template steps, it will be reflected to all other cases too. Content has been taken from this link

[Can test cases have "shared steps" in HP Quality Center?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/10136/can-test-cases-have-shared-steps-in-hp-quality-center)